# python extract digit values from string via regular expressions and list comprehension

Tags: python, expression

I want to extract this

```
3.76    2.35    3.30    5.08     NaN    8.44    10.00
3.76    2.35    3.30    4.99    6.63    8.42    10.00
1.50    1.50    1.60    2.00    2.60    3.35    3.85
NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     0.00    0.00
```

from the following return of an bs4 operation:

```
[<td class="font-bold">Ergebnis je Aktie (unverwässert, nach Steuern)</td>, <td>3,76</td>, 
<td>2,35</td>, <td>3,30</td>, <td>5,08</td>, <td>-</td>, <td>8,44</td>, <td>10,00</td>, <td class="font-
bold">Ergebnis je Aktie (verwässert, nach Steuern)</td>, <td>3,76</td>, <td>2,35</td>, <td>3,30</td>,
 <td>4,99</td>, <td>6,63</td>, <td>8,42</td>, <td>10,00</td>, <td class="font-bold">Dividende je 
Aktie</td>, <td>1,50</td>, <td>1,50</td>, <td>1,60</td>, <td>2,00</td>, <td>2,60</td>, <td>3,35</td>,
 <td>3,85</td>, <td class="font-bold">Gesamtdividendenausschüttung in Mio.</td>, <td>-</td>, <td>-</td>,
 <td>-</td>, <td>-</td>, <td>-</td>, <td>0,00</td>, <td>0,00</td>]
```

I tried something like

```
def get_table_entries(element, len_colums):    
        #--------------------------------
        #
        _re_digits = re.compile("-?\d+\.?\d+")
        #--------------------------------
        # find all table entries
        entries = []
        temp = element.findAll("td")
        temp = str(temp)
        #print(temp)
        #--------------------------------
        # replace elements and extract digits from string
        temp = temp.replace('.', '') 
        temp = temp.replace(',', '.')

        print(temp)
        entries += [ n for n in _re_digits.findall(temp)]
        #--------------------------------
        # reshape output array to fit original table shape and return entries
        print(entries)
        entries = np.reshape(entries, (-1, len_colums))

        return entries
```

But this solution also kicks the minus in `<td>-</td>` I want to transform into NaN. But still when i keep the minus and replace it via  `temp = temp.replace('-', 'NaN')` I will get an error in the following list comprehension.

Comment: just chage your code from 
 _re_digits = re.compile("-?\d+\.?\d+")
To,
 _re_digits = re.compile("-?\d+\,?\d+")

and add replace feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps simplest will be to define a helper function:

```
def to_float(s): 
    if s == "-": 
        return float("nan") 
    else: 
        return float(s.replace(",", "."))
```

And then just write a basic loop over cells:

```
values = []
for elem in soup.find_all("td"): 
    try: 
        values.append(to_float(elem.text)) 
    except ValueError: 
        pass
```

Now it will be easy to convert to numpy array of desired shape:

```
>>> np.array(values).reshape(-1, 7)
array([[ 3.76,  2.35,  3.3 ,  5.08,   nan,  8.44, 10.  ],
       [ 3.76,  2.35,  3.3 ,  4.99,  6.63,  8.42, 10.  ],
       [ 1.5 ,  1.5 ,  1.6 ,  2.  ,  2.6 ,  3.35,  3.85],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,  0.  ,  0.  ]])
```

Comment: Well this is working great! :)
I just changed 

""" else: 
        s = s.replace('.', '')
        s = s.replace(',', '.')
        return float(s)""" because some tables have "." and ",".

Comment: This will require soap module, he wants this with regular expression.

Comment: @Mr.J  I think they have already this module, since the question says: *from the following return of an bs4 operation*

Comment: Any further idea how to handle entries like: < 0 * and > 100 *? But in a more general way.